# What is a Channel in Netty IO?

Tags: netty

Can someone say what is actually a CHANNEL means in Netty-IO? Is it a socket connection? a thread? a queue? or something else. I know it's very basic and silly, but if I understand this then I can understand/visualize the concepts of Netty-IO.

Answer (score 1):

A channel is a abstraction for a Object that allows to performing read/write operation very similar to file descriptor in Unix that is a handle to either a file or a socket or a device. Look at the Javadoc of [NIO channel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channel.html).